# StreamReader not finding strings in file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, streamreader

I have an issue with a SteamReader. My StreamReader won't find a specific string match in a file even though I know the string exists. The best way to show this is through an image. You would get a better understanding of how it works. I will provide code after:
[image]

The Image shows the code which checks to see if the string is in the file. The open text document is the file that is checked. This is passed as a variable when the new form (this form) is create after inputting the information.The form button is the button which runs the code as shown. If the string is not found, the message box is shown.

As you can see the file contians the string but simply doesn't pick it up :/

I suspect this is something very simple but I need a fresh pair of eyes. Here is the code:

```
private void btnGetActivities_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(sVenueName.ToString() + ".txt"))
        {
            using (StreamReader RetrieveEvents = new StreamReader(sVenueName.ToString() + ".txt"))                    //Create a new file with the name of the username variable
            {
                string EventString;
                string EventType;
                string EventPeopleAttending;
                string line = RetrieveEvents.ReadLine();                                        //Declare string variable to hold each line in the file

                while (RetrieveEvents.Peek() != -1)
                {


                    if (line.Contains("Event Name:")) //When this line is found,
                    {
                        EventString = line.Remove(0, 12);                         //Remove the characters from the line and store it in a variable
                        lstDisplayActivities.Items.Add(line);

                        line.Skip(1).Take(2);
                        EventType = line.Remove(0, 12);
                        lstDisplayActivities.Items.Add(line);

                        line.Skip(2).Take(3);
                        EventPeopleAttending = line.Remove(0, 18);
                        lstDisplayActivities.Items.Add(line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No Files were found");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well it's normal you're getting the message box not all your lines have `Event Name:`.

Comment: What do you think this line will do? _line.Skip(1).Take(2);_

Comment: You should get that message 4/5 times dependent on how many lines there are. Probably hold that back until the end of the `while()`

Comment: Also you are not getting a new line within the loop

Comment: @vipersassassin He is reading just one line. It will never see the other lines.

Comment: StreamReader is a waste of time unless you expect the file to be BIG.  Just `File.ReadAllLines` and process the resulting array of lines.  It's also easier to inspect when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading only the first line from the StreamReader. The other lines are never read. You need a loop and at each loop read again a line

```
    string line = RetrieveEvents.ReadLine();                                        
    while (RetrieveEvents.Peek() != -1)
    {
        if (line.Contains("Event Name:")) //When this line is found,
        {
            EventString = line.Remove(0, 12);                         
            lstDisplayActivities.Items.Add(line);

        }
        else if(line.Contains("Event Type:"))
        {
            EventType = line.Remove(0, 12);
            lstDisplayActivities.Items.Add(line);
        }
        else if(line.Contains("People Attending:"))
        {
            EventPeopleAttending = line.Remove(0, 18);
            lstDisplayActivities.Items.Add(line);
        }

        // This reads the next line.....
        line = RetrieveEvents.ReadLine()
    }
}
```

The lines

```
 line.Skip(1).Take(2)
```

and the likes don't advance to the next lines but they simply skip the number of chars in line (1) and then take the following 2 chars just to discard everything you don't assign it to anything

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what @CNuts said in the comments

```
if (line.Contains("Event Name:")) //When this line is found,
{
     //Do stuff
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Files were found");
}
```

Since not all the lines in the file contain "Event Name:" every time the line does not contain this particular string you will get the message "No Files were found".

Here's a suggestion:

```
bool eventsFound = false
while (RetrieveEvents.Peek() != -1)
{
    if (line.Contains("Event Name:")) //When this line is found,
    {
        //Do stuff
        eventsFound = true;
    }
    line = RetrieveEvents.ReadLine();
}
if(!eventsFound)
    MessageBox.Show("No Files were found");
```